# Write struct in a file, C

Tags: c, file

I need to do a program to save some stracts in a file and then load to the program when I open it.
My struct is:

```
struct agenda {
    int idContacte;
    char nom[50];
    struct agenda *segContacte;
};
struct agenda *pAgenda;
struct agenda *pPrimer = NULL;
struct agenda *pIndex;
```

I get the data to my program this way:

```
while (fread(pAgenda, sizeof(struct agenda), 1, f) > 0){
            pAgenda = (struct agenda *)malloc(sizeof(struct agenda));
            printf("%d", pAgenda->idContacte);
            printf("%s", pAgenda->nom);
}
```

And i save to a file this way:

```
pIndex = pPrimer;
    while(pIndex){
        fwrite(pIndex, sizeof(struct agenda), 1, f);
        fclose(f);
        pIndex = pIndex->segContacte;
}
```

The problem is when i open the program, if there is a struct saved on the file, the program clashes. I dont need to save *segContacte on the file and i think this is the problem.
When i save a struct in the file with id 6 and Name Albert te resutl of the file is this(i open the file whit binary option):

`Albert T_CHECK=NO HOMEDRIVE=C: HOMEPATH=\Users\Alber`

Comment: What alk said. Also note that your next pointer `segContacte` will very likely be invalid after reading it again. You should proably only save the raw data id and name and think of a way to create the linked list from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while reading data from file, your code should look like this...

```
while(1)
{
    pAgenda = (struct agenda *)malloc(sizeof(struct agenda));
    if(fread(pAgenda, sizeof(struct agenda), 1, f)==0)
      break;
    printf("%d", pAgenda->idContacte);
    printf("%s", pAgenda->nom);
}
```

------------------------------------
If segContacte is not required to be stored to file, your code can look like this (for writing into file)...

```
pIndex = pPrimer;
while(pIndex){
fwrite(&pIndex->idContacte, sizeof(int), 1, f);
fwrite(pIndex->nom,50,1,f);
pIndex = pIndex->segContacte;
}
fclose(f);
```

accordingly, you should read each record in two parts from file .

```
if(fread(&pIndex->idContacte, sizeof(int), 1, f)==0)
  break;
fread(pIndex->nom,50,1,f);
```

Comment: I do this, now the program dont crash. But still saving something in the file but when reading, the program dont get any data. If there is something in the file, the program go to the first if:
`if(fread(pAgenda, sizeof(struct agenda), 1, f)==0)
      break;`
And then dont read the file.`
I think it is because it save wrong. In the file always are the name i insertet and then a random rute from my HD like this:`    Albert T_CHECK=NO HOMEDRIVE=C: HOMEPATH=\Users\Alber    `

Comment: the "something" in the file is garbage data, as we are storing 50bytes of data using `fwrite(pIndex->nom,50,1,f);`

Comment: suppose, pIndex->nom holds a string "hello" in its 50byte location (the nom[50] in the structure), we certainly store the 44garbage characters. Out of 50, 5 are "hello", 1 is '\0' and remaining 44 are unknown(garbage) characters. If we do not want that data to be stored in the file, make sure the array contains '\0' (NULL) characters in the 50 locations before actual data is placed in the array **nom**.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is on reading code.You are using pAgenda before allocating memory for it.

```
while (fread(pAgenda, sizeof(struct agenda), 1, f) > 0){ 
            pAgenda = (struct agenda *)malloc(sizeof(struct agenda));
            printf("%d", pAgenda->idContacte);
            printf("%s", pAgenda->nom);
}
```

The above code should be like this

```
do { 
   pAgenda = (struct agenda *)malloc(sizeof(struct agenda));
   printf("%d", pAgenda->idContacte);
   printf("%s", pAgenda->nom);
} while (fread(pAgenda, sizeof(struct agenda), 1, f) > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You read first into where `pAgenda` points to (which is a random value on the 1st  iteration) then you allocated memory to it.

Do this the other way round. This is: 1st allocated memory to `pAgenda`, then read into where it points to.